# showing errors even though display_errors is off

Tags: 8, debugging

I want to hide all error messages to the users. I did all the three steps below

1. Set display_errors = off and error_reporting = 32767 in php.ini
2. Made sure this config `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';` not exist in settings.php
3. Admin->Configuration->Development->Logging and Errors -> set `None` for `Error messages to display` config.

Still it is showing all the errors, but on first time load only (E.g If there was an error in previous page, those errors are displayed in current page. If i do refresh, those errors are gone from the pages).

How really can hide all the error messages in Drupal 8? I just want to log the messages not to display.

Comment: Isn't that a 500 error?

Comment: yes it is. But i want to hide that error also to user. Do i need to do anything else to hide that?

Comment: The only thing I can think of for a 500 error is (if you are using Apache) setting a custom 500 error file to display that doesn't look like a 500 error. How else should the stack react to this?

Comment: What is the setting do you have on `/admin/config/development/logging` ?

Comment: I have set as `None`.

Comment: The logic exception isn't really something you can hide, this is not a valid response, you must return something, for example `return new Response('', 204);` like the cron controller.

Comment: I updated the question, as i am not only getting 500 error, but all the error messages in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 hide error messages by default unless you enable dev mode.

Check and remove services.yml and settings.local.php files in sites/default folder.

Comment: What should be removed from services.yml file? I know I need to remove `$config['system.logging']['error_level']='verbose';` from settings.php file. But could you help me on what changes has to be done in services.yml file?

Comment: Set debug to false or just remove files if it there.